# How can I copy columns from several files into the same output file using Perl

Tags: perl

This is my problem.

I need to copy 2 columns each from 7 different files to the same output file. 
All input and output files are CSV files.
And I need to add each new pair of columns beside the columns that have already been copied, so that at the end the output file has 14 columns.

I believe I cannot use

```
open(FILEHANDLE,">>file.csv").
```

Also all 7 CSV files have nearlly 20,000 rows each, therefore I'm reading and writing the files line by line.

It would be a great help if you could give me an idea as to what I should do.

Thanx a lot in advance.

Comment: BTW, do you need to combine data from different rows, or rows with the same number are guaranteed to be related?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your lines are 1:1 (Meaning you're combining data from line 1 of File_1, File_2, etc):

- open all 7 files for input
- open output file
- read line of data from all input files
- write line of combined data to output file

Comment: oh ok, I'll try that out, thanx a lot.                           But just for referance is there anyway I could determine the horizontal position of the 3rd column, if I am to open the 2nd input file after closing the 1st input file?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You can't "add columns to a file".

Comment: If you want to do it in serial as you describe, you would have to close the first input file, close the output file, open the second input file, open the previous output file for reading, then write to a new output file the combined lines of data.

Comment: @Ayodya On most systems you have to think in terms of lines: You read lines(s) and write line(s). You can't read a column or write a column.

Answer (score 1):

[Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) is probably *the* way to access CSV files.

You could define a csv handler for each file (including output),  use `getline` or `getline_hr` (returns hashref) methods to fetch data, combine it into arrayrefs, than use `print`.

Comment: thanx, I'm not very familiar with Text::CSV, so I'll look into it and see.